# mysql query 3 tables

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT     favourites.FavouriteID, 
           favourites.User, 
           favourites.RecipeID,
           recipes.RecipeID,
           recipes.Name,
           recipes.CategoryID,
           recipes.RatingTotal,
           recipes.ImageMed,    
           count(ratings.RecipeID) AS trates ,
           (recipes.RatingTotal / COUNT(ratings.RecipeID)) as avg
FROM       favourites
                  RIGHT JOIN recipes 
                         on recipes.RecipeID = favourites.RecipeID
                  LEFT JOIN ratings 
                         ON ratings.RecipeID = recipes.RecipeID
WHERE favourites.user = '$Cuser' 
GROUP BY ratings.RecipeID 
ORDER BY avg  DESC, trates DESC  
LIMIT  $offset,20
```

hi there this query brings through a total of 3 records but they are 7 , there other 4 don't come through as they do not have a record in the ratings table, how can i adjust ?

the favourites table conatains the recipe id of a recipe which a user has added to theor favourites list , i am trying in the query to display the recipes from the favourites table orded by the one's withthe highet raring first. but the ones that do not have a rating are not showing

Comment: @MoyedAnsari here you go :
Ratings : RatingID,RecipeID,User
favourites : FavouriteID,RecipeID,User
Recipes :  RecipeID,RecipeName

Comment: the favourites table conatains the recipe id of a recipe which a user has added to theor favourites list , i am trying in the query to display the recipes from the favourites table orded by the one's withthe highet raring first. but the ones that do not have a rating are not showing

Comment: replace right join with left join on recipes, hope this work

Comment: @MoyedAnsari nope doesn't sort it out. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be in the data. Maybe the relational integrity between favourites and recipes is violated. Show your test data.